# Relationship User and children data using belongsTo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

$item = Item::where([
    'status' => '1',
    'id' => $id
])->first();

$user = User::where([
    id=>Auth::id()
])->with('children')->get()

return view('item.list')->with(compact('item', 'user'));
```

How can I get item and authenticated user along with children and send it to view in one query or is there any other best practise.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like **Item** is not related in any way to the **User** model.  If that is the case, there is likely no reason to try to do this in one query, and likely not efficient or even possible.  There could be some relation that I don't know of, but you are probably better off doing the two queries.. One for the `$item`:

```
 $Item = Item::where([
    'status' => '1',
    'id' => $id
  ])->first();
```

And then one to load the `children` on the **User** object.  This one is potentially a little different.  If you are manually loading the **User** object for some reason, you can eager load the `children`:

```
$user = User::where([
  'id' => $someId
])->with('children')->first();
```

If you are within the `auth` middleware, you don't need to re-load the user, it is already provided by Laravel.  You can just load the children if they are not already there:

```
 $user->load('children');
```

or, even easier, from your blade page, just call the load on the page:

```
$user->children();
```

You have the code correct for sending to your view:

```
return view('item.list')->with(compact('item', 'user'));
```

Comment: @Viru45 please mark as correct using the checkbox below the voting buttons if you found this helpful.